# Best way to find moving function for a bot

Tags: bots, reverse-engineering, dll-injection

I am working on an online bot for a MMORPG for educational purpose. I want to move my character as I do when I click somewhere with my mouse. I currently found a function which receives the X, Y, Z coordinates in the world whenever I click on the ground, but modifing those values do not change where the character is moving (he gets "warped" back to the original place, so he doesn't move at all) so I dropped the idea on hooking this function.

My question now is, what is the best way to let your bot move?

Comment: educational purpose, eh? ;) you might wanna take a look at this answer: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2176/2147

Comment: ;) Yeah I already saw that post, but I need to find the function which gets called when I press a button on the keyboard. I already tried to simulate it with post message, but this doesn't work for the CryEngine. Any other ideas?